# Insertar dato en java con LinkedList

Tags: java, lista

¿Cómo puede crear un objeto con LinkedList? He probado con add que es lo que he leido y encontrado pero me da error.
Tengo las siguientes clases:

```
public class Notas {
    private double nota;
    private String Asignatura;
    private String fecha;
```

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Persona {
    private String nombre;
    private int numero;
    public LinkedList<Notas> matricula;
        .
        .
        .

    public void insertar(Notas nota) {

        matricula.add(nota);
    }
```

En el main tengo:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Notas prueba = new Notas(8.5, "Quimica", "11 Febrero 2020");
    Persona fernando = new Persona("Fernando Marin Alonso", 15);
    fernando.insertar(prueba);
```

El error que me muestra es:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Persona.insertar(Persona.java:33)
    at Main.main(Pruebas.java:53)
```

Comment: Inicializa la variable `matricula`. Ej: `public LinkedList<Notas> matricula = new LinkedList<>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas usar los metodos de la clase LinkedList. No puedes hacer una asignación directa. Ya que es un array necesitaras añadir un indice -o añadir al final-.

Si no estoy equivocado ArrayList comparte los métodos de LinkedList al ser Listas
Podrías probar `this.matricula.add(matricula)` para añadir.

Comment: Ya esta solucionado pero muchas gracias por ayudar :) El problema estaba en el constructor

Answer (score 4):

Probando tu código, añadiendo unos pequeños matices como los métodos constructores y los `getter/setter` quedaría de la siguiente manera, una posible solución. Imprimo el resultado en el `Main` con `S.O.Println.`

**Notas:**

```
package aulas;

public class Notas {
    private double nota;
    private String asignatura;
    private String fecha;

    public Notas(double nota, String asignatura, String fecha) {
        this.nota = nota;
        this.asignatura = asignatura;
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public double getNota() {
        return nota;
    }

    public void setNota(double nota) {
        this.nota = nota;
    }

    public String getAsignatura() {
        return asignatura;
    }

    public void setAsignatura(String asignatura) {
        this.asignatura = asignatura;
    }

    public String getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(String fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Notas{" + "nota=" + nota + ", asignatura=" + asignatura + ", fecha=" + fecha + '}';
    }

}
```

**Persona:**

```
package aulas;

import aulas.Notas;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Persona {
    private String nombre;
    private int numero;
    public LinkedList<Notas> matricula = new LinkedList<>();

    public Persona(String nombre, int numero) { 
        this.nombre = nombre; 
        this.numero =numero; 
        LinkedList<Notas> matricula = new LinkedList<Notas>(); 
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public LinkedList<Notas> getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(LinkedList<Notas> matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Persona{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", numero=" + numero + ", matricula=" + matricula + '}';
    }

    /**
     * Insertar notas al LinkedList.
     * @param nota 
     */
    public void insertar(Notas nota) {
        matricula.add(nota);
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
package aulas;

import aulas.Notas;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Notas n = new Notas(8.5, "Quimica", "11 Febrero 2020");
        Persona p = new Persona("Fernando Marin Alonso", 15);

        p.insertar(n);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

**Salida por pantalla:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Asegúrate de inicializar la lista matricula en el constructor de la clase Persona. Además, deberías cambiar en la clase Notas la variable "Asignatura" por "asignatura"

```
public Persona(String nombre, int numero) { 
    this.nombre = nombre; 
    this.numero =numero; 
    this.matricula = new LinkedList<Notas>(); 
}
```

```
public class Notas {
    private double nota;
    private String asignatura;
    private String fecha;
}
```

Comment: ```public Persona(String nombre, int numero) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.numero =numero;
        LinkedList<Notas> matricula = new LinkedList<Notas>();
    }``` Ese constructor tenia creado

Comment: ¿Cambiando el nombre de la variable asignatura sigue sin funcionar?

Comment: Si sigue sin funcionar :( pero aun asi gracias por intentar ayudar, seguiré probando cosas a ver si lo saco

Comment: @Paulax A mi me funciona perfectamente. Añadiendo el método constructor de cada clase, y con el método toString(). Si quieres te adjunto mi código.

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta de que el constructor está mal. Tienes que poner this.matricula = new LinkedList<Notas>();

Comment: Agrega el código de como debe quedar. De otro modo la respuesta parece más un comentario.

Comment: Cierto  Gonzalo-GC era eso   -.-

Comment: Muchisimas gracias a todos !!!!!!!